# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem. The version is within range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, rubygems, bundler

Bundler is giving this error when I run `bundle install`, but `actionmailer` 5.2.6 is within the range >= 5.2 and < 8! Why is it giving an error? It's doing this for multiple gems. The dependency is within range for all of them.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    exception_notification (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.5.0, which depends on
      actionmailer (< 8, >= 5.2)

    rails (~> 5.2.6) was resolved to 5.2.6, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 5.2.6)
```

Here is an example of another nonsensical error. Obviously 5.0 <= 5.2.6 < 7:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2.6)

    rails_admin (~> 2.0.1) was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      rails (>= 5.0, < 7)
```

I deleted `Gemfile.lock`. Bundler version 2.3.9. [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/457a3e25e1d04c05a6549ee21c95f1fa)

Comment: Would be a lot easier to answer if you post your gemfile.

Comment: @anonymus_rex [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/457a3e25e1d04c05a6549ee21c95f1fa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of this line:

```
gem 'flip', '~>1.1', :git => 'https://github.com/pda/flip.git'
```

When commented, it works. When uncommented, it spits out nonsensical errors and buried in the errors is this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    flip (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0, <= 5.2)

    rails (~> 5.2.6) was resolved to 5.2.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.2.6)
```

I think that is the ONLY error it should have printed out, but that is probably a bug in Bundler. Now I must manually implement that Gem or think of a monkey patch. (I dislike unnecessary and superficial dependencies.)

Comment: You can point your Gemfile to install [this fork](https://github.com/pda/flip/pull/59) or make your own fork with just the change to the `.gemspec` file.